# Check in C++ that a struct is well aligned or contains gaps

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem that a struct shall be checked - at compile time - if it is well aligned or if it contains gaps.
The checking may be done in additional test code, but I don't want "packed" data in the real implementation code.

This is an example header file (MyData.h) with the typical include guards:

```
#ifndef MYDATA_H_
#define MYDATA_H_

struct uneven
{
  int bla_u32;
  short bla_u16;
  char bla_u8;
  /* <-- this gap will be filled in the unpacked version */
};

#endif // MYDATA_H
```

I found one possible solution - see below.

**Questions:**

- Is there an elegant way to check if the struct `uneven` contains a different number of bytes compared to its unpacked counterpart at *compile time*?
- Is there maybe even a solution that will work in C (without using a namespace)?

Comment: What do you mean with checking may be done in additional test code ? Do you want to have control over placing the assertion in your code ?
Otherwise you could just define a function (similar to what @Dutow suggested) combined with your static assert implementation for each new struct that you want to have compile time checked.

Comment: "checking may be done in additional test code" just means, that the check (also static assert) may be done in additional c or cpp files that are not part of the released code base or the actual product (e.g. using additional compiler flags or something that should not be part of the actual release)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a function instead of a namespace ([on ideone](https://ideone.com/bPyGMq)):

This solution also works in C

Header File:

```
typedef struct
{
  int bla_u32;
  short bla_u16;
  char bla_u8;

  /* <-- this gap will be filled in the unpacked version */
}  uneven;
```

Source File:

```
#include "MyData.h"

#define StaticAssert(cond, msg) switch(0){case 0:case cond:;}

void checkSizes()
{
  uneven unpacked_uneven;
#pragma pack(push, 1)
  #undef MYDATA_H_ // force re-including "MyData.h"
  #include "MyData.h"
#pragma pack(pop)
  uneven packed_uneven;
  StaticAssert(sizeof(unpacked_uneven) == sizeof(packed_uneven), "uneven contains gaps");
}
```

You can place your `StaticAssert` into the function for a compile time error.

Comment: I adapted the solution from Dutow to match my example code - I think this is quite the hack, but I'd go with this common solution if it wasn't for the compiler warning -Wpadded (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38613971/2056545))

Answer (score 5):

A compiler specific solution that works for both C and C++: GCC has a warning option `-Wpadded`, that produces a warning for every definition that change size due to alignment.

Comment: this is great - and so much easier! :) - unfortunately it is gcc specific. Instead of -Wpadded directly in the makefile (to prevent checking of system includes) I would use

   `#pragma GCC diagnostic push`

    `#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wpadded"`

    .... code with structs

    `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop`

Answer (score 2):

I found one (somehow nasty and very tricky) solution for the problem that only works with C++, not C.

```
#define StaticAssert(cond, msg) switch(0){case 0:case cond:;}

#pragma pack(push, 1)
namespace packed
{
#include "MyData.h"
}
#pragma pack(pop)

#undef MYDATA_H_ // force re-including "MyData.h"
#include "MyData.h"

void checkSizes()
{
  StaticAssert(sizeof(packed::uneven) == sizeof(uneven), "uneven contains gaps");
}
```

This `StaticAssert`macro fails for the given uneven struct data - as the packed version's size is of 7 bytes and the unpacked (normal) version is 8 bytes. If an additional `char`is added at the end of the struct the test succeeds - both versions have 8 bytes then.

Comment: You can avoid the namespace by using a nested struct.

Comment: @Dutow which doesn't help with C compatibility, because structs don't have a scope in C

Comment: Alternatively, `#define uneven packed_uneven #include "MyData.h" #undef uneven`.